# Removing duplicate elements in using the function "remove"

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I tried to remove duplicate elements from a vector by a function `vectorremove`, using  the function `remove` from the library of algorithms, but it does not work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void vectorremove(vector<string> v)
{
    for (vector<string>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        vector<string>::iterator end = remove(it + 1, v.end(), *it);
        v.erase(end, v.end());
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> vect;
    string x;

    while (cin >> x)
    {
        vect.push_back(x);
    }

    vectorremove(vect);

    for (vector<string>::iterator it = vect.begin(); it != vect.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this code to test if the function `vectorremove` works, unfortunately it seems that `vectorremove` has no impact on the vector. Have I made any mistake in the use of `remove` in the definition of `vectorremove`?

Comment: `it` is invalidated by the `erase` operation, instead of doing `++it` you should use the return value of `erase`

Comment: Also you pass the vector by value to the vectorremove function, so `vect` in `main` is unchanged

Comment: @M.M Can you please elaborate how to use the return value of ```erase``` instead of ```++it```?

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from opening your C++ book to the chapter that shows you how to use `erase`(), and read the examples that use `erase()`'s return value, by yourself? This is something basic that should be explained in every C++ book, and stackoverflow.com is not a replacement for a C++ book.

Comment: Look up "erase-remove idiom". Or read documentation for `vector::erase`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why std::vector iterator is invalidated after the erase() call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899608/why-stdvector-iterator-is-invalidated-after-the-erase-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem in your code is that you are passing the vector by value and not by reference to `vectorremove`. You need to change that to

```
void vectorremove(vector<string>& v);
```

Then inside your `vectorremove` function you have another problems. `vector::erase` can invalidate all iterators, so you should onle `remove` inside the loop and do the `erase` after the loop.

```
void vectorremove(vector<string>& v)
{
    vector<string>::iterator end{ v.end() };
    for (vector<string>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != end; ++it)
    {
        end = remove(it + 1, end, *it);
    }
    v.erase(end, v.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are passing `std::vector` by value, not by reference. Therefore, any changes you make in `vectorremove` function won't be visible in `main`.
Furthermore, `std::vector::erase` might invalidate iterators so you must not use it inside the loop.

Your code could look like:

```cpp
void vectorremove(std::vector<std::string>& v) {
    auto end{ v.end() };
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != end; ++it)
    {
        end = std::remove(it + 1, end, *it);
    }
    v.erase(end, v.end());
}
```

Note the usage of ***auto*** instead of `std::vector<std::string>::iterator`.

However, STL provides handy functions to achieve what you want. One of them is [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) which

> Eliminates all but the first element from every consecutive group of
>   equivalent elements from the range [first, last) and returns a
>   past-the-end iterator for the new logical end of the range.

In order to remove duplicates from the `std::vector`, you can do something like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()  {
    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end()); // 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 7 
    auto last = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end());
    v.erase(last, v.end());
    for (auto const i : v) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Remember that `std::unique` works as expected **only on sorted** `std::vector`s.

Answer (score 0):

You only modify the copy of vector , you have to pass by reference to modify the actual
vector, why you don't use auto instead of std::vector::iterator. and you have to 
know that  erase invalidates  all iterators pointing to the erased element and 
beyond the erased element, keep the iterator valid by using erase's return value, also  use std::getline inside the loop to store the value from std::cin to include the new line.

**Alternatively** your can use std::unique removes the duplicate value and works as expected after sorting the elements. and std::unique returns a past the end iterator for the new logical end of the range:-

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> removeDuplicate(std::vector<std::string> & v){

std::vector<std::string> vec;

std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
auto pos = std::unique(std::begin(v), std::end(v));

vec.assign(std::begin(v), pos);
return vec;
}


int main(){

std::vector<std::string> vect{"John", "John", "Paul", "John", "Lucy", "Bob", "Bob"};

auto pureVector = removeDuplicate(vect);

for(auto const & v : pureVector){
    std::cout << v << '\n';
}

}
```