# How can I delink an element from a c++ std::list without deallocating it?

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator, contains

Suppose I have a c++ `std::list` object containing a few elements and an iterator `it` to one of the elements. How can I remove this element from the list but still be able to access it? In other words, I want it delinked from the list, but not deallocated.

Curiously, using `list::erase` does seem to achieve this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::list<int> a;
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);
    auto it = (--a.end());
    a.erase(it);
    cout << *it << endl;   /// outputs '3' anyway, without any error
}
```

But I assume this isn't really safe?

Questions:

1. Is it a guarantee behavior that an element erased by `list::erase` is still accessible by the original iterator?
2. If yes, how can I deallocate its memory?
3. If no, how can I erase some element without deallocating its memory and be able access it after erasal?

Comment: `How can I remove this element from the list but still be able to access it? In other words, I want it de-linked from the list, but not deallocated.` This is not possible. Its either in the list or it isn't, there is no inbetween. `If no, how can I erase some element without deallocating its memory and be able access it after erasal?` Copy it out?

Comment: @tkausl Copying might be a bit troublesome for me. Since I have more than one iterators pointing to the same element.

Comment: @ihdv See the same example in the [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40899891/12002570) `test.erase( it );
std::cout << *it << std::endl;`

Comment: @AnoopRana I see. So `it` in my case is in fact invalid? I noticed that in the link you provided all iterators after the the erased `it` become invalid. But since I am using a `list`, can c++ guarantee all other iterators except the erased one to still be valid?

Comment: @ihdv You can splice the element onto another list.

Comment: @ihdv "*So `it` in my case is in fact invalid?*" - after the erase, yes. "*all iterators after the erased `it` become invalid*" - incorrect. In `std::list`, only iterators to the erased element are invalidated. "*since I am using a `list`, can c++ guarantee all other iterators except the erased one to still be valid?*" - yes. That is part of the design of `std::list` dictated by the standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done provided you don't mind using a second list to receive the erased item

```
auto it = (--a.end());
std::list<int> b;
b.splice(b.end(), a, it);
cout << *it << endl;   /// outputs '3'
```

`splice` removes the `it` element from list `a` and adds it to the end of list `b`. It's a constant time operation and does not invalidate any iterators.

Comment: Incidentally `splice` can also be used as a fast way to reorder items within a single list.